# What are saved in optimizer's state_dict? what "state","param_groups" stands for?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

When we use Adam optimizer, if we want to continue train a network from a pretrained model, we not only should load "model.state_dict", but also "optimizer.state_dict". And, if we modified our network's structure, we should also modify saved optimizer's state_dict to make our loading successful.

But I don't understand some params in saved "optimizer.state_dict". like optim_dict["state"] (dict_keys(['step', 'exp_avg', 'exp_avg_sq', 'max_exp_avg_sq']))and optim_dict['param_groups'][0]['params']. There are many of numbers like these:

```
 b['optimizer_state_dict']['state'].keys()
Out[71]: dict_keys([140623218628000, 140623218628072, 140623218628216, 140623218628360, 140623218628720, 140623218628792, 140623218628936, 140623218629080, 140623218629656, 140623218629728, 140623218629872, 140623218630016, 140623218630376, 140623218630448, 140623218716744, 140623218716816, 140623218717392, 140623218717464, 140623218717608, 140623218717752, 140623218718112, 140623218718184, 140623218718328, 140623218718472, 140623218719048, 140623218719120, 140623218719264, 140623218719408, 140623218719768, 140623218719840, 140623218719984, 140623218720128, 140623218720704, 140623209943112, 140623209943256, 140623209943400, 140623209943760, 140623209943832, 140623209943976, 140623209944120, 140623209944696, 140623209944768, 140623209944912, 140623209945056, 140623209945416, 140623209945488, 140623209945632, 140623209945776, 140623209946352, 140623209946424, 140623209946568, 140623209946712, 140623209947072, 140623210041416, 140623210041560, 140623210041704, 140623244033768, 140623244033840, 140623244033696, 140623244033912, 140623244033984, 140623244070984, 140623244071056, 140623244071128, 140623429501576, 140623244071200, 140623244071272, 140623244071344, 140623244071416, 140623244071488, 140623244071560, 140623244071632, 140623244071848, 140623244071920, 140623244072064, 140623244072208, 140623244072424, 140623244072496, 140623244072640, 140623244072784, 140623244073216, 140623244073288, 140623244073432, 140623244073576, 140623244073792, 140623244073864, 140623244074008, 140623244074152, 140623244074584, 140623244074656, 140623244074800, 140623244074944, 140623218540760, 140623218540832, 140623218540976, 140623218541120, 140623218541552, 140623218541624, 140623218541768, 140623218541912, 140623218542128, 140623218542200, 140623218542344, 140623218542488, 140623218542920, 140623218542992, 140623218543136, 140623218543280, 140623218543496, 140623218543568, 140623218543712, 140623218543856, 140623218544288, 140623218544360, 140623218544504, 140623218626632, 140623218626992, 140623218627064, 140623218627208, 140623218627352, 140623218627784, 140623218629440, 140623218717176, 140623218718832, 140623218720488, 140623209944480, 140623209946136, 140623210043000])
```

---

```
In [44]: b['optimizer_state_dict']['state'][140623218628072].keys()
Out[44]: dict_keys(['step', 'exp_avg', 'exp_avg_sq', 'max_exp_avg_sq'])

In [45]: b['optimizer_state_dict']['state'][140623218628072]['exp_avg'].shape
Out[45]: torch.Size([480])
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In contrast to model's `state_dict`, which saves learnable parameters, the optimizer's `state_dict` contains information about the optimizer’s state (parameters to be optimized), as well as the hyperparameters used.

---

All optimizers in PyTorch need to inherit from the base class [`torch.optim.Optimizer`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.Optimizer). It requires two entries:

- `params (iterable)` – an iterable of `torch.Tensor`s or `dict`s. Specifies what Tensors should be optimized.
- `defaults (dict)`: a `dict` containing default values of optimization options (used when a parameter group doesn’t specify them).

In addition to that, optimizers also support specifying per-parameter options.

> To do this, instead of passing an iterable of `Tensor`s, pass in an iterable of `dict`s. Each of them will define a separate parameter group, and should contain a `params` key, containing a list of parameters belonging to it.

Consider an example,

```
optim.SGD([
                {'params': model.base.parameters()},
                {'params': model.classifier.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-3}
            ], lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9)
```

Here, we have provided the a) `params`, b) default hyperparameters: `lr`, `momentum`, and c) a parameter group. In this case, the `model.base`’s parameters will use the default learning rate of 1e-2, `model.classifier`’s parameters will use a learning rate of 1e-3, and a momentum of 0.9 will be used for all parameters.

---

The `step` (`optimizer.step()`) performs a single optimization step (parameter update), which changes the state of the optimizer.

---

Now, coming to optimizer's `state_dict`, it returns the state of the optimizer as a `dict`. It contains two entries:

- `state` - a `dict` holding current optimization state.
- `param_groups` - a `dict` containing all parameter groups (as discussed above)

---

Some of the hyperparameters are specific to the optimizer or model used e.g.  (used in Adam)

- `exp_avg`: exponential moving average of gradient values
- `exp_avg_sq`: exponential moving average of squared gradient values